# How to create polimorphic methods for interface implementation

Tags: java, oop

I have an interface `I` with a method that allows it to interact with another `I`:

```
public interface I {
    I interactWith(I other);
}
```

Then I have a few classes that implement this interface, let's say `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Some of these interact with any other in the same way, so the implementation of the method is easy. Some others interact in different ways instead depending on the type of the other object, so i.e the interaction `B`-`A` is different from `B`-`C` and `B`-`D`. The naive implementation of the method for `B` would be a mess of typechecking/`instanceof` and feels like there's a better solution, so what's the correct approach?

I tried adding a default method `interactWith(A other)` in both the interface and the `B` class but it never gets called. Why is overloading not choosing the more specific method?

Edit: added sample code, also available here: https://onlinegdb.com/fakHVDDpSX

```
public interface I {
    I interactWith(A other);
    I interactWith(I other);
}
```

```
public class B implements I {
    public I interactWith(A other) {
        System.out.println("I'd like this to get called");
    }

    public I interactWith(I other) {
        System.out.println("this get called even when other is of type A");
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    List<I> list = Arrays.asList(new A(), new B());
    list.get(1).interactWith(list.get(0));
}
```

Comment: *"I tried adding a default method interactWith(A other) in both the interface and the B class but it never gets called."* - Are you sure? Can you provide a [*Minimal reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: As @AlexanderIvanchenko says, you need to edit your question to include your actual code, not just a description of it.

Comment: Sure thing, method expecting `A` would **not** be called because you're passing an argument of type `I` (because you can safely say that all elements  in the `List<I>` are of type `I`). The compiler never performs *down-casting* while resolving method-calls. Therefore, `interactWith(A other)` would **not** be even taken into account as potentially applicable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, in particular how you are declaring variables and their types, I am guessing you are running into a common confusion with how Java does dispatch. You are probably expecting behavior that is known as multiple dispatch, while Java only supports single dispatch. Here's the wikipedia page about multiple dispatch, and how you can kind of emulate that behavior in Java: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Java

The gist is that Java needs to know the static types of both the parameter and the receiver of the method call to be able to choose the more specific overload. For example:

```java
ublic class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I a = new A();  // runtime type is `A` but static type is `I`
        A a2 = new A(); // both runtime and static types are `A`
        I b = new B();  // runtime type is `B` but static type is `I`
        B b2 = new B(); // both runtime and static types are `B`
        C c = new C();
        
        p(b.interactWithOther(a));   // got I Main$A@4617c264
        p(b.interactWithOther(a2));  // got I Main$A@36baf30c even though static type of a2 is A, b is an I, so it "doesn't have" the overloaded method
        p(b.interactWithOther(c));   // got I Main$C@7a81197d
        
        p(b2.interactWithOther(a));  // got I Main$A@4617c264
        p(b2.interactWithOther(a2)); // got A Main$A@36baf30c only in this case is there specific enough type information to call the specific overload
        p(b2.interactWithOther(c));  // got I Main$C@7a81197d
    }
    
    static void p(Object o) { System.out.println(o); }

    static public interface I {
        I interactWithOther(I other);
    }
    
    static class A implements I {
        @Override
        public I interactWithOther(I other) { return other; }
    }
    
    static class B implements I {
        @Override
        public I interactWithOther(I other) { System.out.print("got I "); return other; }
        
        public A interactWithOther(A other) { System.out.print("got A "); return other; }
    }
    
    static class C implements I {
        @Override
        public I interactWithOther(I other) { return other; }
    }
    
    static class D implements I {
        @Override
        public I interactWithOther(I other) { return other; }
    }
}
```

Notice how `got A` is only printed when the static type of the receiver is `B` and the static type of the parameter is `A`, rather than `I`s.

You can play around with it here:
https://replit.com/@anqit/NegligibleMustyDatamining#Main.java

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the reason, where I call the method the static type is not known and so it chooses the interface one.
I guess I can't avoid dynamic typechecking then, or is there a pattern for these situations?

Comment: It depends on your situation, and any solution has pros and cons. If you define `interface I` in a library you write and can edit it, you can do something similar to the example in the Wikipedia article and have methods in `I` for each subclass of it that could default to the general version, but allow subclasses to specify behavior for particular cases. This wouldn't be ideal though if say you were publishing `I` in a library where others might also subclass it. Something like https://replit.com/@anqit/NimbleNeighboringDestination#Main.java

Comment: That replit example isn't perfect, as the receiver still needs to be known. There is always `instanceOf`...

Comment: It's not really a solution for me as the interface will be exported so it could potentially be extended/implemented but I understood the issue and I'll think of another solution, thanks

Comment: gotcha. curious what you come up with!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demonstration how polymorphic behavior is working in the situation you've described.

According to [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) the compiler determines all potentially applicable methods maps the call to the most specific method:

> 15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature
>
> ...
>
> The process of determining applicability begins by determining the
> potentially applicable methods (§15.12.2.1). Then, to ensure
> compatibility with the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0,
> the process continues in three phases:
>
> 1. The first phase **performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or the use of variable arity method
>    invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then
>    processing continues to the second phase.

*Example:*

public interface I {
I interactWith(I other);
default I interactWith(Foo other) {
return null;
}
}

```
public static class Foo implements I {
    @Override
    public I interactWith(I other) {
        System.out.println("Foo.interactWith(I other) is called");
        return null;
    }
}

public static class Bar implements I {
    @Override
    public I interactWith(I other) {
        System.out.println("Bar.interactWith(I other) is called");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public I interactWith(Foo other) {
        System.out.println("Bar.interactWith(Foo other) is called");
        return null;
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.interactWith(bar); // method that expects super type `I` would be called
    bar.interactWith(foo); // method that expects `Foo` as the most specific one would be called
}
```

*Output:*

```
Foo.interactWith(I other) is called
Bar.interactWith(Foo other) is called
```